# Nuget package distribution requests wrong version at runtime, probably due to previous upgrade

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a vs2019 C# project that references a Nuget project called Diffplex. Even though the first time we downloaded Diffplex it was version 1.7.0.0, we have since upgraded via nuget to 1.7.1.0.

When we make a distribution of our program, we include Diffplex 1.7.1.0 in the file set. Yet when we run our program, it errors with the screenshot provided.

I did find the "answer" to this. Which was to include the ".exe.config" file in the distribution. However I am not satisfied here. When I look at the app.config of my program, there is this binding redirect statement, presumably added by the nuget process:

```html
 <dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="DiffPlex" publicKeyToken="1d35e91d1bd7bc0f" culture="neutral" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.7.1.0" newVersion="1.7.1.0" /></dependentAssembly>
```

I am guessing that is why I needed the .exe.config file.

However, I do not understand the error's reference to version 1.7.0.0, like its still looking for that version, like it was linked to that version. There is NO reference to 1.7.0.0 anywhere that I can find within this project. No old copies of DLL's lying around, no mentions in any files within the solution. The only thing I know is that this was the version the first time we downloaded this nuget package.

I think 2 things, that I'm not sure are correct.  1. I should not need any binding redirect statements if I am compiling to the same version I am distributing.  2. There is a bug in either VS or nuget causing the old version to stick around and cause problems.

Can anyone explain this behavior? We are starting to distrust nuget as this is the only time we see this behavior, and I don't want that to be the case.

Thanks,
Dave

[image: .NET Framework version error]

Comment: While I voted to close as "missing [mre]" I don't think this question can be made suitable for SO. There is no way you going to be able to post your whole installed set of files inline in the question (which is where "the anywhere" is - you need to ILSpy/ILDasm each assembly and find the one that references the mismatched binaries)... At very least consider showing error as text and list of references for most suspicious assemblies as text too (ILDasm is your friend there).

Comment: Have you tried to check the version of  `DiffPlex` under References? The first thing you mentioned , you can remove binding redirects.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that another assembly you are using is referencing the old dll(1.7.0.0). You can check all of the other project references being used and make sure if they have a reference to the DiffPlex dlls.

Go to the solution explorer and choose DiffPlex under References, right-click and say properties. Check the version and modify the version to 1.7.1.0 if you want to use new version.

[image]

Or as the exception message says, it wants 1.7.0.0 but you give it 1.7.1.0  with bindingRedirect element in app.config file . The problem is that the bindingRedirect works. You can remove  your binding redirects in app.config and then it will reference the old version.